# Javascript boolean and prototype

Tags: javascript

The function is designed to count the objects with type: cow and hadCalf: null and store the value to numToBreed, I always get zero in console. Why?

```
var forestCows = [
  {name: "Marcus", type: "calf", hadCalf: null},
  {name: "Isaiah", type: "bull", hadCalf: null},
  {name: "Lemuel", type: "cow", hadCalf: null},
  {name: "Daniel", type: "cow", hadCalf: null},
  {name: "Joseph", type: "cow", hadCalf: "Legolas"}
];
Object.prototype.noCalvesYet=function(){
  if(this.type=="cow" && this.hadCalf==null){
  return true;}
  else{return false;}
};
Array.prototype.countForBreeding=function(){
var numToBreed=0;
for(var i=0;i<this.length;i++){
  this[i].noCalvesYet();
  if(this[i].noCalvesYet===true){
    numToBreed++;
    }
}
return numToBreed;
};

var store=forestCows.countForBreeding();
console.log(store);
```

Also I tried to create a new function to better understand the boolean within conditional "if"

```
var executeThis=function(){return true;};
executeThis();

if(executeThis===true){console.log(3+5);}
```

In this case, nothing is shown in console, why?

`

`

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
...
for(var i=0;i<this.length;i++){
  if(this[i].noCalvesYet()===true){
    numToBreed++;
    }
}
...
```

error here, this not call method noCalvesYet:

```
if(this[i].noCalvesYet===true)
```

Comment: Can you explain why it doesn't work? I called this[i].noCalvesYet() first and since the value of noCalvesYet is returned(true or false), then it should work. I need an explanation why it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with if statement, change:

```
if(this[i].noCalvesYet === true) {
   numToBreed++;
}
```

to:

```
if(this[i].noCalvesYet() === true){
   numToBreed++;
}
```

You was checking object property instead of function result.

Comment: If I put a function within an object, can it take boolean values of true or false?

Comment: Setting property is different thing then returning the value. You can not have the same property name and method name. To cache value you can use different property and assign it inside method. But in your example it has no sense. Just call method once inside if operator.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't add methods to built-in, native objects. What you're doing there, with `Object.prototype` and `Array.prototype` is wrong.

Here's why:

- http://perfectionkills.com/extending-native-builtins/
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/287827/whats-wrong-about-extending-a-class-with-prototype-methods

Here is the correct code, based on your logic:

```js
var forestCows = [
  {name: "Marcus", type: "calf", hadCalf: null},
  {name: "Isaiah", type: "bull", hadCalf: null},
  {name: "Lemuel", type: "cow", hadCalf: null},
  {name: "Daniel", type: "cow", hadCalf: null},
  {name: "Joseph", type: "cow", hadCalf: "Legolas"}
];

function countForBreeding(cattle) {
  // store the length of the array so we don't access it every time
  var cattleCount = cattle.length;

  // set a default value
  var numToBreed = 0;

  // iterate over the list
  for (var i = 0; i < cattleCount; i++) {
    // verify if our current cow/bull/calf had a calf
    if (hadCalf(cattle[i])) {

      // increment if true
      numToBreed++;
    }
  }

  return numToBreed;
}

function hadCalf(cow) {
  // verify if we have a cow and if it did not have a calf
  if (cow.type === 'cow' && cow.hadCalf === null) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

var cowsForBreeding = countForBreeding(forestCows);
console.log(cowsForBreeding);
```

The problem with your approach is that you are not calling functions properly:

```
if(this[i].noCalvesYet===true){
    numToBreed++;
}
```

should be

```
if(this[i].noCalvesYet() ===true){
    numToBreed++;
}
```

You need to execute the noCalvesYet function.

A simpler example would be to use the built in Array.prototype.filter function and combine it with Array.prototype.reduce. You could then filter through your cattle list, and narrow down to only those that match your criteria: cow and no calf and then simply return the length of that list.

```js
var forestCows = [
  {name: "Marcus", type: "calf", hadCalf: null},
  {name: "Isaiah", type: "bull", hadCalf: null},
  {name: "Lemuel", type: "cow", hadCalf: null},
  {name: "Daniel", type: "cow", hadCalf: null},
  {name: "Joseph", type: "cow", hadCalf: "Legolas"}
];

var cowsForBreeding = forestCows.filter(function(cow) {
  return cow.type === 'cow' && cow.hadCalf === null;
});

console.log(cowsForBreeding.length);
```

Cheers!

Comment: Actually I started JS a week ago and learn it via Codeschool, As of now I'm on the early stages of learning Prototype and I'm still trying to comprehend it very carefully. Cheers!

Comment: That's nice! Good luck! You can also try this book: http://eloquentjavascript.net/ . It's very beginner-friendly, packed with exercises and doesn't employ academic language or anything else that might complicate things even more.

Answer (score -1):

A function call doesn't store its return value back to itself. You need to use the return value immediatey by either assigning it to a variable or using the function call directly where you need the value. In other words either:

```js
var executeThis = function() { 
  return true; 
};

var result = executeThis();

if( result === true ) { 
  console.log(3+5);
}
```

Or, skip the variable and call the function at the same time when you test its return value.

```js
var executeThis = function() { 
  return true; 
};

if( executeThis() === true ) { 
  console.log(3+5);
}
```

The token `executeThis` without parentheses is always a reference to the function itself, never to its return value.

Comment: Thanks, this explains my problem. :)